# Number of layers in nested convex hull

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Find the maximum number of nested convex hull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum number of layers is clearly $1$, which happens iff all your points are extreme points (for instance, when they are all on a circle).

The maximum number of layers is probably $\lceil n/3\rceil$, which happens when you have nested triangles.

This bound is for the plane. In dimension $d$, it should be $d+1$ instead of $3$.

Comment: Yes I understood it will be a nested triangle for maximum triangle.But how it is ceeling of n/3

Comment: sorry for spelling mistake and it will be maximum layers

Comment: @user3621835, because a convex layers has to have at least 3 vertices, except perhaps for the last one, which may have 1 or 2.

Comment: If the last one has 1 or 2 vertices, then will it be a convex hull? In the question it is said that the process continues until there is no point left. Then if there are 2 or 1 points left, then how it will be a convex layer? convex layer should be closed not open

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

- The convex hull of $n$ points in general position in $d$-dimensional space may have from $(d+1)$ to $n$ vertices.
- The convex hull of points in non-general position may have only $2$ vertices even in high dimensions (it may have 1, but there won't be any layers then).
- In $\mathbb{R}^d$, as long as your convex hull has non-empty interior, whatever figure you have, you can scale it down so that it fits strictly inside (i.e. it doesn't even "touch" the boundary of the hull).

I hope it helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I have n't understood point number 2 and 3. What is meant by non general position? I want to find the maximum and minimum number of convex layers as a function of n(number of points). Can I form a mathematical formula for this

Answer (score 0):

Here's a worst-case example, and it occurs in dimension 1.  your set of $n$ points has $n$ odd, $n = 2k + 1$. The points are at position $-k, -k + 1, \ldots, -1, 0, 1, 2, \ldots k$ on the $x$-axis.

The first convex hull consists of the points at $-k$ and $k$; the next consists of points at $-k + 1$ and $k-1$, and so on. The total number of hulls: $k + 1 = \frac{n+1}{2}$.

You can generalize this to $p$ dimensions -- place all the points on the $x$-axis in a higher-dimensional space. This is clearly a degenerate case -- usually points don't all lie on a line! -- but it's still one you have to consider. On the other hand, whether this example "works" depends on your definition.

I say "depending on definition" because in this example, the inner $n-2$ points may or may not be considered as part of the "hull". If you want to consider them part of the hull, and you're working in the plane, then the previous answer is good: roughly $n/3$ sequential hulls, and you'd better round up just to be safe (think of a triangle with a point at its center!).